# Android Drag-Sort-Listview - programatically initiate drag/drop

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, drag

I am working with the drag-sort-listview` I found [here](https://github.com/JayH5/drag-sort-listview).

Is there a way for me to initiate a drag and drop operation programmatically?  For example, imagine a `ListView` that contains 5 items.  As soon as a user clicks the `CheckBox` of the top item, I would like that item to 'move' to the bottom of the list, just as if the user had 'dragged' it there himself.

I have searched for days for an answer and simply can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

For advance animations in a list or animating items in a list, you should always use RecyclerView. It is much faster and have prebuilt functions to generate these kind of effects.

Here is the documentation of recyclerview: http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html